# Why is pnorm giving different results with X, sd and mean vs corresponding z value?

Tags: r, probability, normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function

I have to calculate $P(X < 6)$ for $X \sim N(7,5)$. When I entered `pnorm(6, mean=7, sd=5)` into `R`, it gave me a result of `[1] 0.4207403`, which I knew wasn't right (it's a university practice question). I calculated $Z = \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} = \frac{6-7}{\sqrt5} = -0.45$ myself and plugged that into `R` as `pnum(-.45)` to double-check. It gave me `[1] 0.3263552` as the result, which is the correct answer. I checked the documentation and did some sleuthing here and otherplaces online, but couldn't find out where the discrepancy comes from. Why is `pnorm` giving these two different answers in this case?

Comment: There's no inconsistency here other than that you're using $\sigma=5$ in the first formula and $\sigma^2=5$ in the second. `pnorm(6, 7, sqrt(5))` will match the latter.

Comment: The correct value for z is -1/5.

Comment: @PBulls Thanks for the answer. Absolutely overlooked that...

Comment: @PBulls you could make that an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inconsistency stems from the use of $\sigma=5$ in the `pnorm` call, whereas your original specification and second formula have $\sigma^2=5$.

The usual notation of $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ implies that you should use $\sqrt 5$ for the standard deviation argument as you did in the denominator when standardizing:

```r
pnorm(6, mean=7, sd=sqrt(5))
> 0.3273604

all.equal(pnorm(6, 7, sqrt(5)), pnorm((6 - 7) / sqrt(5)))
> TRUE
```